# Sitecore 9.2 Campaign Creator not showing data in experience analytics

Tags: habitat

Not sure why the out of the box feature of sitecore didnt work in one go :) so need a little help here

Problem statement

- I have created a simple campaign via campaign creator
- Associated that campaign to my Habitat home page item.
- Also, I am using the campaign id and browsing few pages of website.
- But no luck with data appearing in Experience Analytics
- I didnt find any error in logs.
- All the services are up and running
- Experience Analytics is showing other data for logged in user on its dashboard

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced same issue at some point. If xConnect services are running, and no xDB connection problems in xConnect logs (this was my problem) then you can try to deploy Marketing Definitions from Control Panel, Analytic sections. I also noticed that campaigns data does not show up immediately after user session has ended.